# My preferences aren't 'sticking'

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a settings section for my app. I have a res/xml/settings.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <ListPreference 
    android:key="numberOfYears"
    android:title="Number of Years to Read the Bible"
    android:summary="How many years would you like to take to read through the reading plan?"
    android:entries="@array/numberOfYears"
    android:entryValues="@array/numberOfYears"
    android:dialogTitle="How Many Years?"
    />
  <CheckBoxPreference android:key="ignoreDates"
    android:title="Ignore Dates"
    android:summary="Would you like to use the dates in the plan?"
  />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have a class called Preferences which extends PreferenceActivity and contains the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
```

I wasn't sure if this was required but I also added the following to my main activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, PREFS_MENU, Menu.NONE, "Preferences");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Menu Item: " + item.getItemId());
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case PREFS_MENU :
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This seems to work in that I get a "Preferences" menu which, when selected, launches my preferences.  However, when I select anything the values don't seem to stick.  My understanding was that the android:key was enough for the system to set the chosen values in the default shared preferences - is this not the case?

What am I missing?

Comment: "when I select anything the values don't seem to stick" -- what is your definition of this? Here is a sample project that works: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/

Comment: If I go in and set the preference, press back, and then go in again then the preferences are unset.  That's what I mean by not sticking.  I'll take look at your project though.  Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, if I use adb to go and look at the shared preferences - the values are set.  Why then, do they not show up when setting the preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I did this correctly and I would love to have inputs or another best or better practices as well.

I made my PreferenceActivity class also implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, and have these methods implemented like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Preference pref = findPreference(arg1);
    if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference)pref;
        pref.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
    }
    else {
        pref.setSummary(arg0.getString(arg1, pref.getSummary().toString()));
    }
}
```